# MySQL select percentage

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table "tblfavs" with five columns: id, userid, logoid, favdate, did.

I want to determine the percentage of a user's (userid) favorites (id) that share the same designer id (did), and where userid <> did, displayed from highest percentage to lowest.

In pseudo-query format:

```
SELECT [percentage], userid, did
FROM tblfavs
WHERE record has the same userid and did
AND userid <> did
GROUP BY userid
ORDER BY [percentage] DESC
```

I can't get my head around the query to accomplish this. Help appreciated!

**Edit:**

Sample data

```
1, 1, 5, 2017-01-01, 2
2, 7, 3, 2017-01-02, 5
3, 1, 8, 2017-01-02, 2
4, 7, 1, 2017-01-02, 3
```

In this set user 1 (second column) has two entries and both have "2" as the designer id (final column).

Expected output

```
100%, userid 1, did 2
50%, userid 7, did 5
50%, userid 7, did 3
etc.
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it? It would make it easier for us to help you

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: Sample data and expected output added, hoping this is what you had in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easier in other DBMS which feature window functions (e.g. `COUNT OVER`). However, this is not that difficult in MySQL either. You just need two aggregations: Count per `userid` and `did`, count per `userid`, divide.

```
select
  ud.cnt * 100.0 / u.cnt as percentage,
  ud.userid,
  ud.did
from
(
  select userid, did, count(*) as cnt
  from tblfavs
  group by userid, did
) ud
join
(
  select userid, count(*) as cnt
  from tblfavs
  group by userid
) u on u.userid = ud.userid
order by percentage desc;
```

Comment: I am in awe. In my world, that's a monster query. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Try this (improved from the previous answer to match your exact input-so you get % for each row not agregated)

```
select
    ud.cnt2 * 100.0 / u.cnt as percentage,
    ud.userid,
    ud.did
from
(
    select
        out3.userid,out3.did, cnt2
    from
        (select userid,did from tblfavs) out3
    join
    (
       select 
         userid, did, count(*) as cnt2
       from tblfavs
        group by userid, did
    ) ud on ud.userid = out3.userid and ud.did = out3.did
) ud
join
(
    select userid, count(*) as cnt
    from tblfavs
    group by userid
) u on u.userid = ud.userid
order by percentage desc;
```